# In search for a complete definition for write-only TMs / Tapes

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity, space-complexity, computation-models

In the following lines I will present my question, whose content is divided in two parts: ***Preparation*** and ***Actual*** .

### (1) — Preparation

Regarding the formal definition of the ***(one tape) general Turing Machine***, I was able to rephrase the definition from the corresponding Wikipedia article
( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine ) in the following manner:

> A (one-tape) general Turing machine can be formally defined as a 7-tuple $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$ where:
>
> - $Q \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of states
> - $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of tape alphabet symbols
> - $b\in \Gamma$ is the blank symbol
> - $\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma \setminus \{b\}$ is the set of input alphabet symbols
> - $\delta :(Q\setminus F)\times \Gamma \to Q\times \Gamma \times \{\leftarrow,\rightarrow\}$ is the transition function
>   <sub>( $\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ are the Left Shift option and the Right Shift option, respectively)</sub>
> - $q_{0}\in Q$ is the initial state
> - $F\subseteq Q$ is the set of accepting states

---

Regarding the formal definition of the ***(one tape) read-only Turing Machine***, I have checked the contents of the corresponding Wikipedia article ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_Turing_machine ) and I have found a definition that corresponds to the definition of the ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** I have rephrased initially, but where ***the following remark*** is made:

> So given initial state $q$ reading symbol $a$, we have a transition defined by $\delta (q,a)=(q_{2},a_{2},d)$ which replaces $a$ with $a_{2}$, transitions to state $q_{2}$, and moves the "read head" in direction $d$ (left or right) to read the next input. In our 2DFA read-only machine, however, $a=a_{2}$ always.

Therefore, as $a$ is always equal to $a_{2}$ in a ***(one-tape) read-only Turing Machine***, I assumed that one of the parameters may be ommited and thus, that a ***(one tape) read-only Turing Machine*** can be defined as a ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$, with the only change being the fact that its transition function has to be:

> $\delta :(Q\setminus F)\times \Gamma \to Q\times \{\leftarrow, \rightarrow\}$

<sup>( notice the missing $\Gamma$ in the ***codomain*** of the transition function, compared to the transition function of the ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** )</sup>

Therefore, the following definition would be obtained:

> A (one-tape) read-only Turing machine can be formally defined as a 7-tuple $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$ where:
>
> - $Q \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of states
> - $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of tape alphabet symbols
> - $b\in \Gamma$ is the blank symbol
> - $\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma \setminus \{b\}$ is the set of input alphabet symbols
> - $\delta :(Q\setminus F)\times \Gamma \to Q\times \{\leftarrow, \rightarrow\}$ is the transition function
>   <sub>( $\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ are the Left Shift option and the Right Shift option, respectively)</sub>
> - $q_{0}\in Q$ is the initial state
> - $F\subseteq Q$ is the set of accepting states

---

Regarding the formal definition of the ***(one tape) Turing Machine with Stay option***, I have checked the contents of the corresponding GeeksForGeeks article ( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modifications-to-standard-turing-machine/ ) and I have found a definition that corresponds to the definition of the ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** I have rephrased initially, but where ***the following remark*** is made:

> Instead of moving left or right on seeing an input, the head could also stay at one position without moving anywhere.

Therefore, since a Stay option is also permitted next to the Left shift option and Right shift option in a ***(one-tape) Turing Machine with Stay option***, I assumed that the ***(one tape) Turing Machine with Stay option*** can be defined as a ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$, with the only change being the fact that its transition function has to be:

> $\delta :(Q\setminus F)\times \Gamma \to Q\times \Gamma \times \{\leftarrow,—,\rightarrow\}$

<sup>( notice the new $—$, the ***Stay option***, in the ***codomain*** of the transition function, compared to the transition function of the ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** )</sup>

Therefore, the following definition would be obtained:

> A (one-tape) Turing machine with Stay option can be formally defined as a 7-tuple $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$ where:
>
> - $Q \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of states
> - $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of tape alphabet symbols
> - $b\in \Gamma$ is the blank symbol
> - $\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma \setminus \{b\}$ is the set of input alphabet symbols
> - $\delta :(Q\setminus F)\times \Gamma \to Q\times \Gamma \times \{\leftarrow,—,\rightarrow\}$ is the transition function
>   <sub>( $\leftarrow$, $—$ and $\rightarrow$ are the Left Shift option, the Stay option and the Right Shift option, respectively)</sub>
> - $q_{0}\in Q$ is the initial state
> - $F\subseteq Q$ is the set of accepting states

---

### (2) — Actual

Under the assumption that what I declared until now is correctly stated, I try to ***deduce a correct definition for a (one tape) write-only Turing Machine with Stay option***.

Following the characteristics stated by the definitions of both the Turing Machines presented beforehand, the ***(one tape) read-only Turing Machine*** and the ***(one tape) Turing Machine with Stay option***, I assume that the ***(one tape) write-only Turing Machine with Stay option*** can be defined as a ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$, with the only change being the fact that its transition function has to be:

> $\delta :(Q\setminus F) \to Q\times \Gamma \times \{\leftarrow,—,\rightarrow\}$

<sup>( notice the missing $\Gamma$ in the ***domain*** of the transition function ***and*** the new $—$, the ***Stay option***, in the ***codomain*** of the transition function, compared to the transition function of the ***(one tape) general Turing Machine*** )</sup>

Therefore, the following definition would be obtained:

> A (one-tape) write-only Turing Machine with Stay option can be formally defined as a 7-tuple $M=\langle Q,\Gamma ,b,\Sigma ,\delta ,q_{0},F\rangle$ where:
>
> - $Q \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of states
> - $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ is a finite set of tape alphabet symbols
> - $b\in \Gamma$ is the blank symbol
> - $\Sigma \subseteq \Gamma \setminus \{b\}$ is the set of input alphabet symbols
> - $\delta :(Q\setminus F) \to Q\times \Gamma \times \{\leftarrow,—,\rightarrow\}$ is the transition function
>   <sub>( $\leftarrow$, $—$ and $\rightarrow$ are the Left Shift option, the Stay option and the Right Shift option, respectively)</sub>
> - $q_{0}\in Q$ is the initial state
> - $F\subseteq Q$ is the set of accepting states

---

#### Question:

Since I could not have found almost any information on the Internet regarding the formal definition of the ***(one tape) write-only Turing Machine*** with ***or*** without ***Stay option***, I am interested to know ***how correct is my reasoning and final definition of the (one-tape) write-only Turing Machine with Stay option that I have obtained***, since my purpose is to include the formal definition of the ***(one tape) write-only Turing Machine with Stay option*** I have stated in one of my research papers, for future use.

<sup>*One may argue about the lack of practical use with regards to a ***(one tape) read/write-only Turing Machine*** with any further characteristics — this is the reason for which I also state the following ***extension*** of this question, whose answer presents a big interest for me.*</sup>

---

#### Extension:

How easy may one ***establish a relation*** between the formal definition of a ***(one tape) Turing Machine*** with given characteristics and the formal definition for a ***specific tape*** inside an other ***multi-tape Turing Machine***, that has the same characteristics as the previously defined ***(one tape) Turing Machine***.

As an example, being known a complete definition of a simple ***(one tape) read-only Turing Machine***, can I easily develop a complete definition of a ***specific tape*** inside a ***multi-tape Turing Machine*** that ***must be read-only*** for some purpose? Therefore, how easy can I declare ***analytically*** that, in a ***multi-tape Turing Machine***, there is a ***specific tape*** that is ***read-only***?

---

Thank you for your implication in reading and analyzing my question.

Looking forward to your answer(s) !

Alex

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I don't understand what your second question is asking.

Comment: @D.W. I have made some edits in the question. Please take into consideration rechecking its clarified content and coming with an answer to the question. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to ask how correct is your definition.  Definitions just are; they are not correct or incorrect (what standard would you use to measure their correctness by?).  We discourage "please check my reasoning" questions, because the only possible answer is "good/no good", which is unlikely to help future visitors.  I don't understand what you mean by "how easy" or what kind of relation you're hoping for.  I don't know what you mean by "a complete definition of a specific tape inside a multi-tape Turing machine" or by "analytically".  Please ask only one question per post.